# Creating id for Android Views

Tags: android

This question is quite basic. Let me go with an example.
I have two activities

> - activity_a.xml
> - ActivityA.java
> - activity_b.xml
> - ActivityB.java

Both the XML files contain only a TextView to display a simple text. As usual, the TextViews are going to be referenced in the corresponding `.java` files using their View id

My question is, if it is right to reference the TextView in both the XML files with same id? (like using the below code with exactly same id for activity_a.xml and activity_b.xml)

```
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">
  <TextView
  android:id="@+id/textview"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

I was practising this procedure without any problems. When trying to reach the corresponding xml code for the TextView using **Ctrl + Click** (on Windows), I am provided with two options (to display the TextView's xml code from *activity_a.xml* or from *activity_b.xml*).

Also, what is the recommended way to name a View in Android? This will be helpful, when your Android project contains multiple layout files.

Comment: Thanks everyone. You cleared my doubt

Comment: but, why provide me with -ve ratings?. I mean what's wrong with my question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> if it is right to reference the TextView in both the XML files with same id?

It is totally fine, the compiler will only look at the ID under a single view hierarchy.

e.g.: `findViewById(R.id.textview)` inside `ActivityA.java` will only search for textview ID inside `activity_a.xml` (assuming you have `setContentView(R.layout.activity_a);` beforehand.

> what is the recommended way to name a View in Android?

In my opinion, you just need to be consistent in naming your view throughout the app. The main goal is to avoid misinterpretation and confusion.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

Yes , if you have same name of view or view group in different layout then it tells from which layout file it belongs to, ask for select required layout file.

so for that you have to follow proper naming conventions to avoid this type of confusion

https://github.com/ribot/android-guidelines/blob/master/project_and_code_guidelines.md

or you can give name like 
`activity_home_tvUserName` if username textview from home activity
and
`activity_profile_tvUserName` if username textview from profile activity.

Answer (score 0):

They are in different activities, so you should have no problem using the same id. you could event declare them both as `@+id/textview`. However, why not just use the same XML file for both activities? No reason you can't.
You can also create an `ids.xml` file under the values folder and declare all your ids under it, so you don't have to declare them in your layouts, but this is not a very common approach.

Answer (score 0):

**if it is right to reference the TextView in both the XML files with same id?**

My answer is **Yes, It is right.**

Whenever we set the `setContentView(R.layout.activity_a)`, then it'll search for the given id within the above activity. Local attribute having the same id will take the more preference over the other attributes with the same id.

But having unique id's is Best practice.